# Plot graph with only some values for category

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to graph the table below.

Expecting to get one line per color.

I have no idea how to set the graph to get the desired result.

Header of the table contains category values (X values).

[image: here].

I have tried different types of graphs and types of axis. No luck.

Comment: What _kind_ of graph do you want? And what is wrong with the graph you did try?

Comment: I want a simple line chart. With graphs I have tried, Excel always plots only those values that are known for every data set I add, so if I add values from red and dark green row I get only shown values for 1,2 and 4. Excel wont show other values fro mred, cause it does not know what to put there for mdakr green row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just selecting the data, then going to `insert - chart - 2d line - line with markers` shows me a chart which seems to be a solution for your issue.

[image]

Comment: I suspect the user's follow-up question, how to get the X axis to show the numbers proportionally, is answered by using an XY Scatter chart, subtype markers and lines, instead of a line chart.